# What astronomical event, if any, do the 6 tekufos correspond to?

Tags: calendar, natural-phenomenon

[Bava Metzia 106b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=22&daf=106b&format=pdf) speaks of 6 *tekufos*

> רשב"ג משום ר"מ אומר וכן היה רבי שמעון בן מנסיא אומר כדבריו חצי תשרי
>   מרחשון וחצי כסליו זרע, חצי כסליו טבת וחצי שבט חורף, חצי שבט אדר וחצי
>   ניסן קור, חצי ניסן אייר וחצי סיון קציר, חצי סיון תמוז וחצי אב קיץ, חצי אב
>   אלול וחצי תשרי חום. רבי יהודה מונה מתשרי ר"ש מונה ממרחשון

which רש"י

> חצי תשרי וכו'. שש **תקופות** שהובטחו לנח ובניו קמפרש

says is based on the pasuk in *parashas Noach*, [B'reshis 8:22](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8172#showrashi=true&v=22)

> עֹד כָּל יְמֵי הָאָרֶץ זֶרַע וְקָצִיר וְקֹר וָחֹם וְקַיִץ וָחֹרֶף וְיוֹם וָלַיְלָה לֹא יִשְׁבֹּתוּ:
>   So long as the earth exists, seed-time and harvest, cold and heat, summer and winter, and day and night shall not cease

The [Yerushalmi in Bikurim 10a](http://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Bikkurim.10a.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) makes reference to Tekufas Shvat (also see P'nei Moshe).

> רבי ירמיה רבי אימי בשם רבי יוחנן רבי סימון בשם רבי יהושע בן לוי הכל
>   מודין שראש השנה שלו בט"ו בשבט. רבי יוחנן שאל לרבי יונתן כסדר של שנים
>   או כסדרן של תקופות. אמר ליה כסדרן של שנים ואפילו שנה מעוברת. ‏

Being these are 2 months each, not 3 months each, they can't correspond to the equinoxes and solstices, so what astronomical event do they correspond to?

Comment: "Tekufases"?? Isn't the word "Tekufot" (or "tekufos")? I think that these events might be more meteorological / climate related than astronomical.

Answer (score 1):

See the Rash"i beginning with קציר on the same page of the Gemarah that you mentioned. These appear to be climatological incidents.

Among them, Rash"i explains that קציר is harvesting that occurs at the beginning of the rainy season, and it is the opposite of זרע that occurs at the beginning of the warm season. The terms in the verse are arrange in pairs of opposites, probably to emphasize the contrasts.

I don't know why Rash"i uses the term תקופות in the one that you cited. But the term means "cycles" (See [here](http://mashiyach.com/tekufah-2) for the "looser" definition.) Note that at the end of the following Rash"i starting with קציר , he uses the term עתים which means "points in time". Perhaps, he should have used this term in the previous commentary.